# Removing a character from a string

Tags: c++, string

i have a string. I want to delete the last character of the string if it is a space.
i tried the following code,

```
str.erase(remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isspace), str.end());
```

but my g++ compiler gives me an error saying:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*,
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >,
__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
std::allocator<char> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

please help.

Comment: c++ but the compiler is g++...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first problem is that `isspace` has multiple overloads in the C++ Standard Library. The initial fix is to provide an explicit type for the function so that the compiler knows which function to take the address of:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "lol hi innit";
   str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), (int(*)(int))isspace), str.end());
   std::cout << str; // will output: "lolhiinnit"
}
```

It's a big ugly but, hey, this is C++.

Second, your code will remove *all* spaces in the string, which is not what you seem to want. Consider a simple if statement on the last character of the string:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
   std::string str = "lol hi innit ";
   assert(!str.empty());

   if (*str.rbegin() == ' ')
      str.resize(str.length()-1);

   std::cout << "[" << str << "]"; // will output: "[lol hi innit]"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 6):

I think it can't figure out what `isspace` is (according to the "unresolved overloaded function type" as a third parameter to `remove_if` in the error message). Try `::isspace`, and include `ctype.h`

Comment: i was trying to use std::isspace.. :P

Comment: I haven't used `std::isspace`, but according to the reference it takes 2 arguments, the second is the locale, so it does not fit as a predicate

Comment: Should be using `#include <cctype>`

Comment: Actually there are two `std::isspace`s; the problem is that the compiler doesn't know _which_ to use. It's _overloaded_. Don't use `::isspace` (residing in the global namespace, where only one of those overloads exists) because it's unspecified whether this is available on any given implementation. Fix your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem as you, so I got rid of `isspace`. I just went with this:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(),str.end(),' '),str.end());
```

That worked for me with Visual C++ 2012, using Visual Studio 2012. See if it works for you.

Answer (score -2):

You are missing an `std::` for `remove_if`

Comment: You have included `<algorithm>` also?

Comment: I mean `#include <algorithm>` .