# std::remove_if and std::isspace - compile-time error

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I have the following code:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), std::isspace), str.end());
}
```

MSVC-11.0 compiles this code without any error, but gcc 4.7.2 gives me the following errors:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:8:66: error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
main.cpp:8:66: note: candidate is:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.7/algorithm:63:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:1160:5: note: template<class _FIter, class _Predicate> _FIter std::remove_if(_FIter, _FIter, _Predicate)
/usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/stl_algo.h:1160:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:8:66: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Predicate’
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985612/remove-if-throw-error-when-trying-to-remove-white-space) question about it, but according to the [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isspace), there isn't any version of this function that takes two arguments. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537930/removing-a-character-from-a-string) question too, but according to the cppreference (yep, again) I see that there's only one std::isspace function overload.

Who's right? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: [Here's the other `std::isspace` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace). It's unfortunate cppreference's search doesn't find both.

Comment: @dyp the search doesn't, but "See also" at the bottom of each page links to the other one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is [another overload of `std::isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/isspace), so you need to specify which one to use. An easy way is to use a lambda (or write your own one-line function if you don't have C++11 support):

```
std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), 
               [](char c){ 
                  return std::isspace(static_cast<unsigned char>(c));
               });
```

Answer (score 7):

`std::isspace` is an overloaded function, although the two overloads reside in different headers. Also note that your code may introduce undefined behaviour because only values in the range `0..UCHAR_MAX` can be passed to `std::isspace`, whereas a `char` is possibly signed.

Here is a solution:

```
std::string str;
auto f = [](unsigned char const c) { return std::isspace(c); };
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), f), str.end());
```

Comment: Yes, the mismatch between `is`* taking values between 0 and `UCHAR_MAX` and usually signed `char` is really evil. Renders the `is`* functions basically useless.

Comment: @JanHudec: AFAIK `char`'s signedness is an implementation detail. Where I work we use a gcc switch to guarantee that it's unsigned, I would suppose that other compilers may support this option too... but it is a pain for anything non-ASCII (which in a world of Unicode... oh well)

Comment: @MatthieuM.: It is implementation detail, but default is signed in all compilers, while the functions only work with unsigned. And any code that attempts to be reuseable can't rely on compiler switches.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Actually, the correct way seems to be `std::isspace(std::char_traits<char>::to_int_type(c))`; this function always converts `char` to positive integer so that `-1` remains reserved for eof. Of course it does not have to be done when using the functions that return `std::istream::traits_type::int_type`, because the stream already did.

Comment: @JanHudec: so obvious :/ C++ needs a serious overhaul of its character handling, it shows it was created before Unicode was hype.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: The unicode stuff in C++ does not help things at all. Especially because the locale support often does not actually work.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should get you around the compile-time error:

```
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), (int(*) (int)) std::isspace), str.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

After C++ 11, you can use lamda function (easier to understand), see below:

```cpp
string s = " 3/  2";

auto isSpace = [](const unsigned char c) 
{
    return std::isspace(c);
};
s.erase(remove_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isSpace), s.end());
```

Output:

```
3/2
```