What am I doing wrong when using remove_if function
I am attempting to remove leading whitespace from a string read in from a file. Why won't remove_if work (I'm using C++20)?
line is a std::string.
For some reason remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::isspace); is throwing me the following error. What am I doing wrong?
error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if'
            remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::isspace);
            ^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/remove_if.h:24:1: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Predicate'
remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
^


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?. Also please post a [mre], and the exact error message, as copy-pasted text.

There are actually multiple isspace functions available. You need to explicitly use std::isspace. On a related issue: What's the problem with "using namespace std;"?.

error: no matching function for call to 'remove_if'
remove_if(line.begin(), line.end(), std::isspace);
^~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1/__algorithm/remove_if.h:24:1: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Predicate'
remove_if(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last, _Predicate __pred)
^

It seems you have managed to get both std::isspace and std::isspace (yes they are two different functions). The best solution is to use a lambda to do the check: std::remove_if(..., [](char ch) { return std::isspace(ch) != 0; });

Also don't forget to call std::erase after your call std::remove_if

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21578544/stdremove-if-and-stdisspace-compile-time-error

std::isspace is not an addressible function, so you cannot take its address.
